# Cannot get ScrollView to work in app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

My app has two sections, stuff to do for today, and for upcoming days.

I am able to hide/show these by pressing on the corresponding button but when I open both, there can be too much info and I can only scroll the listview for the upcoming days and not the entire screen.

I did some searching and I kept seeing ScrollView pop up but I can't get that to work, it crashes my app.

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="eu.agp_it.agpmobilemover.OverviewActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/layout_button_today">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/overview_button_today"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.95"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/overview_today"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_buttonoverview"
                android:onClick="buttonTodayOnClick"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_listview_today"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_button_today">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listviewtoday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"

                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_button_upcoming"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_listview_today">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/overview_button_upcoming"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.95"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/overview_upcoming"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_buttonoverview"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
                android:onClick="buttonUpcomingOnClick"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_listview_upcoming"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_button_upcoming">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listviewupcoming"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"

                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: a) you have to post your crash log. b) You are only allowed to have one child view inside `ScrollView`, you can put a `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` and put everything in that view. c) You should not be putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView` d) You shouldn't be putting more than one `ListView` in a view.

Comment: @Sharj but if I should be putting multiple ListViews in a view, how can I list both the assignment for today and upcoming days?

Comment: you can handle that in your `ListView` adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the ScrollView at all.  The ListViews already do the scrolling for you.  Nesting scrolling views isn't recommended.

Try taking out the ScrollView.  Each LinearLayout could take up half the screen, or whatever amount you'd like.  You could also use an ExpandableListView which would allow you to expand and collapse the assignments for today and upcoming days based on their header (Today, Upcoming).  This way you would only need one ListView.  So it would be easier to maintain.

Comment: I will try using an ExpandableListView, thanks for the info!

Comment: Just saw some examples for ExpandableListViews and I don't think I'm able to put as much info on them as I need to :/ I need multiple buttons and multiple text fields so I guess I can just try and make my solution without the ScrollView as usable as possible.